# Как из данного списка сделать строку?

Tags: python, строки, list

Input

```
[[['Apple', ['Red']], ['Banana', ['Yellow']]]
```

Output

```
"Apple Red,Banana Yellow"
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться генератором с распаковкой элементов списка. Промежуточная последовательность склеивается через запятую методом [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

```
data = [['Apple', ['Red']], ['Banana', ['Yellow']]]
output = ",".join(f"{fruit} {color}" for fruit, [color] in data)
print(output)
```